# Are all class methods defined with "def self.foo"? 

Tags: ruby, oop, class-method

Am I right with the following idea? Advice/feedback is greatly appreciated!

---

We can tell which method is instance method and which method is class method by seeing if the keyword `self` has been specified before the method name.

So, the method, for example: `def self.foo_bar` is defined as class method.
On the other hand, the `def foo_bar` is defined as instance method.

Comment: What about `class Apple; def Apple.eat; end; end` ? And using `instance_methods()` ?

Comment: @muistooshort, yep I agree, deleted my misguiding comment. apologies for missing this case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do it that way. Consider this:

```
class C
  class << self
    def m
      puts 'pancakes!'
    end
  end
  def i
    puts 'eggs'
  end
end
```

That gives you a class method `m` on `C` with no "self" in the method's declaration. You can, however, ask the class about it's methods:

```
C.methods.include? :m
# true
C.methods.include? :i
# false
C.instance_methods.include? :i
# true
```

And given how mutable Ruby's classes are, asking the class is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is more ways to define class method besides method with `self.` in the class definition:

```
class A
  def A.method1
  end

  class << self
    def method2
    end
  end
end

A.instance_eval do
  def method3
  end
end

module B
  def method4
  end
end

A.extend B

p A.methods.first(4)

# >> [:method1, :method2, :method3, :method4]
```

Answer (score 0):

As yet another option, you can see all your class method with help of this snippet:

```
class C
  class << self
    def first
    end
  end
  def C.second
  end
  def self.third
  end
end

eigenclass = class << C; self; end
eigenclass.instance_methods(false)  # => [:first, :second, :third]
```

That's because all class methods are instance methods of eigenclass for this Class'es object.